# Snake game in Python using Turtle module

Tags: python

im getting errors:
I tried update python, but there was no update, so just did repair, didnt help

I dont know what do add, im begginer.

```
File "C, line 11, in <module>
    head = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C, line 3814, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "C, line 2558, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C, line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C, line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C, line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator

Process finished with exit code 1
```

deleted paths

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Snake")
window.bgcolor("green")
window.setup(width=600, height=600)
window.tracer(0)

window.mainloop()

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("orange")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"


while True:
    window.update()
```

Comment: What do you do to get that error? The window opens normally for me, and the error only happens if I close it. Then just don't close it...

Comment: The window open normally for me too, but i supposed to see head of the snake, which i cant see

Comment: Hint: Make sure you understand what your code is doing instead of just copying them, especially the `window.mainloop()` line..